# Question regarding affine spaces in infinite dimension vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have this following problem in my problem set (Baby Intro to Functional Analysis). This seems only a problem of Linear Algebra but the "infinite dimensional features" of this course mess up with my mind, most of the time.

**Definition**: An affine space $V$ of a vector space $X$ is a set of vectors such that for any $x,y \in V$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $tx + (1-t)y \in V$.

**Definition**: The *space generated by $V$*, denoted by $[V]$ is defined as the set of all possible linear combinations of elements of $V$. We note that $[V]$ is a vector subspace of $X$ on its own right.

**Definition**: A hyperplane $H$ of a vector space $E$ is a maximal affine space, in the sense that if $H \neq E$ and $H' \supseteq H$ is another affine space of $E$, then $H' = E$ or $H' = H$.

> **Problem:**
>   Let $V$ be an affine space of a vector space $X$ such that $V$ is *not* a vector subspace of $X$. Show that $V$ is hyperplane regarding the vector subspace $[V]$.

**My intuition:** This makes a lot of sense in a finite dimensional setting. If we think of $X = \mathbb{R^3}$, and $V$ as a straight line in the $x,y$ plane that does not intercept the origin (and this must be the case since it's not a vector subspace), then $[V] = \mathbb{R^2}$ and yes, $V$ is a maximal affine space of $[V]$. Although, it does not need to be a hyperplane of the entire space $X$.

I tried to prove it by contradiction, supposing that we can find an affine space $V'$ such that $V' \neq [V]$ and $V' \supset V$. But I couldn't follow on. Any ideas or hints? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since $V \subsetneq V'$, there is $x \in V' \setminus V$. Now, try to show $V' = [V]$.

Comment: I've pursued this path, but no success. The idea is to show that $x$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $V$, right?. Well, suppose it can't. Then $x$ and the vectors in $V$ form a basis for a certain space (that I can't fully characterize). This space contains $V$ and any linear combination of elements of $V$, so it contains $[V]$. Then $[V'] \supset [V]$. But how to follow from here?

Comment: Since $V' \subset [V]$, you have $x = \alpha \, v_1 + \beta \, v_2$ for $v_1, v_2 \in V$ and $\alpha + \beta \ne 0$, $\alpha \ne 0$. Each element in $\tilde v \in [V]$ can be written as $\tilde v = \gamma \, v_1 + \delta \, v_3$ for some $v_3 \in V$. Now, one can check that $\tilde v$ can be written as an affine combination of $x$ and some element in $V$.

Comment: But why is $V' \subset [V]$? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Because you want to show that $V$ is a hyperplane in $[V]$.